# Firebase OTP log in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase

I have written a code to use Firebase to send OTP on a mobile number. I am reaching till a place where OTP is getting generated but seems the code breaks on its way. Any help is much appreciated.

So I have added a jquery ajax call action to give a call to SENDOTP Action method, which further makes an attempt to connect with Firebase for sending the OTP on mobile number

```
public JsonResult SendOTP()
    {
        /* We will use here Random class which will help us generate Random numbers. In NEXT function
         we will pass the limitation of the digit to 6 only*/

        int otpValue = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
        var status = "";

        /*try statement allows us to define a block of code to be tested for error while it is being executed*/

        /*catch statment allows us to define a block of code to be executed, if an error occurs in try statement*/
        try
        {
            //ConfigurationManager enabled us to read a secion from Config File which is Web.config
            //AppSettings is a Getter property of  ConfigurationManager with which we GET data stored

            string recipient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecipientNumber"].ToString();


            string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"].ToString();

            //Here we store our message with concat otpnumber value

            string message = $"Your OTP code is: {otpValue}.";
            String encodedMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);



            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues("https://securetoken.google.com/myApp/", new NameValueCollection(){

                                     {"apiKey" , APIKey},
                                     {"numbers" , recipient},
                                     {"message" , encodedMessage},
                                     {"sender" , "600010"}});

                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);

                status = jsonObject["status"].ToString();

                Session["CurrentOTP"] = otpValue;
            }


            return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw (e);

        }

    }
```

Thanking in advance.